# Highmaps logo string rendering invalid copyright character

Tags: css, highcharts, character, invalid-characters, highmaps

When I create a HighMaps object, the map displays a message at the bottom with an invalid character (see red box):

[image]

This seems to render fine in all of the [demos](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo). Here is the HTML block that gets created when launched on my localhost:

```
<text x="426" text-anchor="end" zIndex="8" style="cursor:pointer;color:#909090;font-size:9px;fill:#909090;" y="395">
    <tspan onclick="location.href=&quot;http://www.highcharts.com&quot;" style="cursor: pointer;">Highcharts</tspan>
    <tspan dx="0"> Â© </tspan>
    <tspan onclick="location.href=&quot;http://www.naturalearthdata.com&quot;" dx="0" style="cursor: pointer;">Natural Earth</tspan>
</text>
```

Comment: Try to set utf-8 encoding of your page file and set correct meta.

Comment: Thanks for some reason that didn't work for me earlier, I must have been using an incorrect meta

Comment: Using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">` fixes the problem

Comment: I added it as answer, do check it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set utf-8 encoding of your page file and set correct meta.